# Applications created in v2 endpoint, how to grant admin consent for all users in my tenant

Tags: azure-active-directory

For v1 app registered in portal, you can 'Grant Permissions' to consent to an application's delegated permissions on behalf of all the users in your tenant. For an app registered in v2 endpoint, can only see it in the 'Enterprise Applications' tab and there is no option for 'grant permissions' in the permissions tab. How to get to the same goal that I do not want individually consent each user?

**Edit**: after make the adminconsent call, 
This worked, (with only graph scope)

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=myappid&response_type=code&response_mode=query&scope=openid profile email offline_access https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FCalendars.ReadWrite%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FContacts.ReadWrite%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FMail.ReadWrite%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FUser.Read&state=12345&redirect_uri=redirecturl
```

This still give me a AADSTS90094 error and ask for admin consent, (with openid scopes)

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=myappid&response_type=code&response_mode=query&scope=openid profile email offline_access https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FCalendars.ReadWrite%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FContacts.ReadWrite%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FMail.ReadWrite%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FUser.Read&state=12345&redirect_uri=redirecturl
```

**Edit**:

> This issue happens only when I turn on 'User Assignment Required' flag

in azure portal, if that flag is disabled, users will be able to individually consent and login, no issues, however we need this flag since we do not want all our users in AD be able to use the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listings in the enterprise apps tab are all service principals rather than app registrations. These are apps that your tenant has signed into & consented thus provisioning the service principal into the tenant.

v2 apps are created and managed through the [App Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com); however, there is no equivalent functionality to `Grant Permissions` at this time.  In order to perform admin consent in v2, you have to construct a request to Azure AD.

Just go to your browser and drop the following request (populated with your regisered apps Client/App ID & Redirect URI:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/adminconsent?client_id=<Client/App ID>&redirect_uri=<App's Redirect URI>&state=111`

Comment: Thanks! Could you please review my edit above, it seems if requesting scope with openid still does not work. thanks

Comment: Does `common` not work for the tenant in this case? How do I initially get the tenant if not? When I do use `common`, I get `AADSTS50020: We are unable to issue tokens from this API version for a Microsoft account. Please contact the application vendor as they need to use version 2.0 of the protocol to support this.`

Comment: `common` should work on the `/adminconsent` endpoint.  The error you linked usually indicates the app you specified was registered on the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com) as a v1.0 application. To perform admin consent on the v2.0 endpoint, it should be a v2.0 app which can be registered at [the app registration portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com).  If you want to do admin consent on a v1.0 app, you can [follow this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview#understanding-user-and-admin-consent).

Answer (score 1):

To request consent for all users in a tenant in Azure AD V2.0, your app can use the admin consent endpoint:

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/adminconsent?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&state=12345
&redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/permissions
```

Please refer to docunment : [Using the admin consent endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-scopes#using-the-admin-consent-endpoint)